# Getting issue on table sorting for dynamically loaded table

Tags: tablesorter

I am loading table row dynamically using ajax and i have a button called load more when user click on load more button 15 more transactions are added in tbody. table sorting is working fine on 1st load But on click of load more button now I have 30 transaction in tbody where my table sorting is only working for descending. But i want it to be sorted ascending and descending both. But Again on 2nd click of loadmore button every thing is working fine. Can any one suggest me what is the wrong with my code.
Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

```
<table class="tablesorter list-table" id='AllPaymentTable'> 

</table> 

<script>
var thead = $("<thead/>").appendTo('#AllPaymentTable');
var PaymentHeader= responseData.data.payment_header_object;
$("<tr/>")
  .append("<th class='name'>" +PaymentHeader[i] + "</th>" )
  .appendTo(thead);

var tbody = $("<tbody/>").appendTo('#AllPaymentTable');

var payActivitydetails = responseData.data.payment_data_object;

for (var i = 0; i < payActivitydetails.length; i++) {
  var payDetails = payActivitydetails[i];
  $("<tr class='recentPaymentrow'  id="+payDetails.payment_id +"/>")
  .append("<td class='name'>" + payDetails.customer_name  + "</td>")
  .appendTo(tbody);
  $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
}

$('#loadmorebtn').bind('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ajax call goes here
  //Recents payment populating on screen starts here
  var payActivitydetails = responseData.data.payment_data_object;
  for (var i = 0; i < payActivitydetails.length; i++) {
    var payDetails = payActivitydetails[i];
    $("<tr class='recentPaymentrow'  id="+payDetails.payment_id +"/>")
      .append("<td class='name'>" + payDetails.customer_name  + "</td>")
      .appendTo('tbody')
    $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've initialized tablesorter, you shouldn't initialize it again. Instead, use the update method to get tablesorter to recognize the change in the table:

```
$("<tr class='recentPaymentrow'  id="+payDetails.payment_id +"/>")
  .append("<td class='name'>" + payDetails.customer_name  + "</td>")
  .appendTo('tbody')
  .trigger('update'); // update method (bubbles up to table)
```